# Integrate Salvattore inside my Aurelia application

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I tried to integrate [Salvattore](https://salvattore.js.org/) (Masonry alternative in CSS) inside my [Aurelia](https://aurelia.io/) app but unfortunately it doesn't work. After trying a lot of things I'm disappointed and think maybe it is not possible at all to have Salvattore working inside an Aurelia app.

Here is what I did: I created a new Aurelia project thanks to the CLI `au new` and inside this project I created an html page inside my Aurelia project with this code:

```
<div id="grid" data-columns>
    <div>Item #1</div>
    <div>Item #2</div>
    <div>Item #3</div>
    <div>Item #4</div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#grid[data-columns]::before {
    content: '3 .column.size-1of3'; 
}

/* These are the classes that are going to be applied: */
.column { float: left; }
.size-1of3 { width: 33.333%; }
```

At first, I tried simply to reference Salvattore's js code inside my index.html page (just above the close body tag) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height />
  </head>

  <body aurelia-app="main">
    <script src="scripts/vendor-bundle.js" data-main="aurelia-bootstrapper"></script>
    <script src="javascript/salvattore.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

It doesn't work, I got errors in the console.

[image]

I also tried to install Salvattore through [npm install salvattore --save](https://www.npmjs.com/package/salvattore) and I add it in the aurelia.json. In `main.ts` I tried to reference it: `import 'salvattore';` but it doesn't work neither. I mean, no errors this time but nothing happened. Finally I tried to inject the Salvattore js script directly inside my page at the end thanks to the [scriptinjector](http://www.sobell.net/calling-external-javascript-from-within-aurelia-templates/) component. Once again, it dosn't work, nothing happened.

Do I have to draw the conclusion that Salvattore is simply not compatible with any Aurelia projects ? In that case, do you know any alternative ?

Below sample codepen using Salvattore in a basic html page (not Aurelia)

https://codepen.io/mitour/pen/wWMOvw

Comment: This looks like something totally irrelevant to either lib. It seems to be more of bundling

Comment: Can you help create a topic in discourse: https://discourse.aurelia.io and paste relevant code?

Comment: also: what version of the cli do you use? and what kind of project? (webpack?)

Comment: The latest CLI version. Not using webpack but the CLI's built-in Bundler Dependency Management.

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand cli bundler is an AMD bundler. Your `<script src="javascript/salvattore.min.js"></script>` is below `vendor-bundle`, so an AMD loader (requirejs/systemjs) is already in place when browser reads `salvattore.min.js`. That's why salvattore tries to load itself as an AMD module instead of creating a global var.

You can move `salvattore.min.js` to above `vendor-bundle` script tag.
Or using prepend in `aurelia.json`, add salvattore before requirejs in the prepend list.

The other thing you can try is to use it as a module. Don't add script tag in html, don't add it prepend. But add this line in your `main.js` or `main.ts`.

```
import "salvattore"; // this will load it as an AMD module
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but unfortunately it doesn't work. Still no effect on my hmtl code.

Comment: Okay, I got it working by simply calling an `inìt` function located inside the javascript source file of Salvattore. I'll post my solution here asap.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

- In **package.json** add `"salvattore": "^1.0.9"`
- In **aurelia.json** add `"salvattore"`

In your typescript page (.ts):

```
 import * as salvattore from 'salvattore';

 export class MyPage {
     attached() {
         salvattore.init();
     } 
 }
```